Functions of Deep Learning: ReLU and two half-planes
In this article by Gilbert Strang, he says that the "The graph of each component of (Av+b)+ has two half-planes". I see why there are two distinct portions, the positive values of Av+b are mapped directly, while negative values are all mapped to 0, but I don't fully understand why there are planes at all.
I also don't understand the part about the input space being sliced into q hyperplanes.
Can someone take a crack at understanding and explaining this? I really want to understand this part of the article.
